# No-bacteria diet

Tags: science-based, food

Suppose there's some strange group that decided to try not consuming any bacteria (which are, basically, *everywhere*. and *very small*). On earth, today.

What would completely forbidding the consumption of bacteria entail for these people?

What foods, if any, could still be consumed? How would one drink? How could a person live?

Comment: Unless your group has technology more advanced than our own, they would not be able to eat or drink anything.

Comment: They're already living _in your mouth_, so not eating them at that point is very difficult indeed.

Comment: They would basically have to have their gastrointestinal tracts removed.

Comment: Just about any pasteurized beverage works, assuming that *dead* bacteia are acceptable. Milk, beer, etc. And of course (many brands of) bottled water; look for "microbiologically pure" on the label.

Comment: Water's doable. But there are some unanswered questions about the consumption of ultrapure water most of which revolve around "will you die if you drink it", usually related to trace salts. Those might be added back, and make it safe to drink. For food, if dead bacteria are allowed, irradiating the food could be sufficient as LDutch pointed out. No idea how what kind of dishwasher it takes to make the cutlery permitted.

Comment: Just breathing will constantly deposit living bacteria in the mouth, nose, throat, and lungs. Not even living in a sealed environment would prevent this, as you are constantly shedding bacteria into your environment.

Comment: low bacteria diets exist for people with compromised immune system but there is no such thing as a bacteria free diet, bacteria are just too omnipresent.  your mouth and gut are full of bacteria anyway.

Answer (score 7):

If they have no objection toward killing the bacteria before eating, they can use gamma irradiation to zero the bacterial charge of any food and therefore eat everything.

Gamma irradiation, by using radioactive cobalt, is used today to sterilise food and objects.

Comment: can't do it for everything though, Gamma also breaks down several essential vitamins  like thiamin and vitamin C.

Comment: Anyway should they end up killing their own gastrointestinal microbiome, they would either die or have to eat bacteria to survive. And this event happens rather often, especially if they would get hit by a bacterial infection and have to take antibiotics to fight it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to ignore the feasability of actually achieving this and assume they have a magical filter in front of their mouth that disintegrates all microorganisms that passes through.

Unfortunately, their lives would probably be pretty miserable.

First, the immune system. There's a hypothesis called the hygene hypothesis[1] that posits that allergies and autoimmune conditions are caused by a lack of exposure to pathogens; the immune system effectively gets bored and starts attacking benign things such as food ingredients - or, worse, the own body. With absolutely no bacteria coming into the system the adaptive immune system would be completely dysfunctional at best, and actively causing chronic hyper-MS-Lupus-Arthritis at worst.

Then, there's the gut microbiome. Research in recent years has shown that the gut-brain axis[2] is surprisingly strong, with things such as mood and brain development being heavily influenced by chemicals produced by your gut microbiome. Without *any* microbiome, it's hard to say what would happen, but it probably wouldn't be pleasant. Gut bacteria also participate in digestion, so without them they would most likely be malnourished as the body can't easily break down complex nutrients that the microbiome would otherwise be doing.

[1] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygiene_hypothesis
[2] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gut%E2%80%93brain_axis

Comment: 50% of our dopamine and 90% of the serotonin comes from gut bacteria. Without those, major depression and other diseases such as Parkinson's are likely.

Comment: @DavidR I don't think that is true, as dopamine and serotonin produced in the gut remain in the gut

Comment: @MS According to https://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/22/15/7931, serotonin passes from the gut into the bloodstream. Here is a review of the various chemicals. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8234057/  Here is a mouse model showing that gut dopamine does affect the brain. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00213-019-05265-5

Comment: @DavidR thanks, looks like i was wrong

Answer (score 1):

#### Easy as Thanksgiving Turkey!

First off, we are going to dispense with the objections in comments and elsewhere regarding the human immune system, omnipresence of bacteria, etc. You're talking about a group with a particular philosophy. Obviously, their philosophy is much like that of some radical non-violence types who sweep the ground they walk on so they won't tread on a bug. Of course, many bugs are too tiny, won't be swept up and will be trodden on all the same. Therefore, we're not worried about bacteria floating in the air, or the normal flora of the body. No, our goal is simply to serve up a delicious meal that is devoid of living bacteria.

Basically all they need is an autoclave. Yep, the same machine that sterilises surgical instruments will not only sterilise Aunt Sadie's favourite silverware, but will also cook the turkey and trimmings! Autoclaves function by pumping steam into a sealed chamber and pressurising the chamber. The inside of the chamber is typically 270deg, and cooking time should probably be 45min to an hour or so for a good sized turkey.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCC51vCx7C8) of an actual turkey being cooked in an actual autoclave, and is thereafter eaten by the actual person who cooked it. Skip to about 0:30 for the meat and potatoes. Apparently, what came out of the autoclave was hot and edible. Yum!